# Instruction-level hooking library for win32?

Tags: windows, x86, x86-64, libraries, hooking

I am looking for instruction-level hooking library for win32 x86/x64.

1. I want to write hook insertion and hook implementation code in C/C++ (compiled into dll).
   (Therefore instrumentation tools are out of question. Injection is not a problem in my case.)
2. I need hooking onto arbitrary addresses.
   I want the hooking library saving registers, call my native function, and then restoring registers, and return/jump to specific addresses.
3. It is very tedious to do this on manually at a per-site basis and therefore I want an existing library. Furthermore, x64 MSVC does not support asm. It seems that manual hook is impossible unless other tool-chain are used?

Does such kind of hooking libraries exists?

Comment: Have a look at https://frida.re/